# can you please provide example how to generate dynamic column and dynamic rows

Tags: angularjs

Can you please provide the example of how to generate the dynamic columns and dynamic rows  using service in controller or ng-repeat in html?

Answer (score 0):

Here there is the official documentation of ngRepeat with some examples

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: thank you.Anyone can provide how to route to second tab controller in callback function when click on the tab2. see example in fiddler link